# Can't add current time-stamp as default in MySql using phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, timestamp

[image]

Trying to create current date column, when I select default 'none' it works. But if I, select current timestamp then, can't create the column.

Comment: try changing Type from DATE to DATETIME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the unmatched type. Select the type as timestamp not date.

[image]

result:

[image]